# log4j configuration loading

Tags: tomcat, log4j

I have several log4j.xml logj configuration file in my tomcat application.
One out of the application in `/home/toto/etc/log4j.xml` and one other in my `WEB-INF/classes/` application.

These two configuration files seems to be loaded but, do you know in which order there are loaded, or if they are merged at the compilation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this parameter to the JVM args to see what log4j is doing, it will then log from where it loads the configuration:

```
-Dlog4j.debug
```

Also if you wish to override them I think log4j.properties file takes precedence over .xml files, so you could create a log4j.properties file.